# Jquery Autocomplete - Autocomplete on input

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using the jquery autocomplete widget where the user types in a number that is associated with a company and other data, and that data is populated in other fields. Currently the user types in the number and then has to select it from a list for the other fields to complete. My goal is to eliminate the user from having to select the number from the list and instead they type in the number, hit the search button and the fields populate. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
$("#moveinbooth").autocomplete({
    source: "/sites/schedule.php",
    change: function (event, ui) {

        if (!ui.item) {
            //http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change -
            // The item selected from the menu, if any. Otherwise the property is null
            //so clear the item for force selection
            $("#moveinbooth").val("");
        }

    },
    minLength: 0,
    position: {
        my: "center bottom",
        at: "center top",
        collision: "flip"
    },
    scroll: false,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).autocomplete('disable');
        $('#exhibitorname').val(ui.item.exhibitor);
        $('#moveindate').val(ui.item.moveindate);
        $('#moveintime').val(ui.item.moveintime);
        $('#moveoutdate').val(ui.item.moveoutdate);
        $('#moveouttime').val(ui.item.moveouttime);
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

If they have to type it, and not select it then do you still need the autocomplete? If you do and your problem is that the user still has to select it in the list, even when the number is fully typed then simply listen for a select event or TAB or ENTER keypress.